# Integrate Sharepoint search (with suggestions) into my browser?

Tags: 2010, search

We're using SharePoint 2010 for our Intranet site and I'd like to integrate the search on the site directly into my browser (so that typing in the address bar gives suggestions from there as well as Google). I was able to add the basic provider via http://www.enhanceie.com/ie/searchbuilder.asp, but it doesn't allow search suggestions.

Can search suggestions be enabled for SharePoint, or is there a specialized URL I can use? I can see in the registry (under my IE search provider) that I don't have a "SuggestionsURL" string (the XML provided by the page linked above doesn't provide a value here), but I've added one with a few different values and no matter what I try, IE crashes as soon as I try to get suggestions from the provider. Regular search works fine and sends me to the intranet search URL with my query already populated, but I'm hoping for suggestions.

Thanks for any help you're able to provide!

Answer (score 0):

Search Suggestions can be enabled on SharePoint 2010. Make sure that

1. "query logging" is enabled on the associated Search Service application
2. The "Query Logging" timer job is enabled and runs
3. The "Prepare Query Suggestions" timer job is enabled and runs